# How to deserialize json to .net type and return it as string

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to send a POST request using Fiddler as so:

```
POST http://localhost:50196/api/values/json HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json;
Host: localhost:50196
Content-Length: 73

{"ssn":1605789787,"creditScore":598,"loanAmount":10.0,"loanDuration":360}
```

This is my WebAPI controller, where I deserialize it to a .NET type which is my POCO. Then I get the ssn and generate a rate which I then want to return.

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [ActionName("json")]
    public string Post(string request)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel>(request);
        var ss = json.Ssn;

        var random = new Random();
        var interestRate = random.Next(100, 500);
        var rate = interestRate / 100;

        var delta = "{\"ssn\":" + ss + ",\"interestRate\":" + rate + "}";

        return delta;

    }

}
```

POCO:

```
public class JsonModel
{
    [JsonProperty("ssn")]
    public string Ssn { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("creditScore")]
    public int CreditScore { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("loanAmount")]
    public decimal LoanAmount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("loanDuration")]
    public int LoanDuration { get; set; }
}
```

WebAPI config:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new {action = @"[a-zA-Z]+", id = @"\*"}
        );
    }
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> [HttpException]: The controller for path '/api/values/json'
>   was not found or does not implement IController. ved
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) ved
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName) ved
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext,  IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   ved System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext,  AsyncCallback callback, Object state) ved
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) ved
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) ved
>                                System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   ved System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are completely missing out in ASP.NET MVC model binding capabilities here, instead of accepting a JSON string in the action and then deserializing, just expect the model and let the framework do the binding for you e.g.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(JsonModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Secondly, your exception is due to a routing problem. You are trying to post to `api/values/json` which is the equivalent to `api/{controller}/{action}`. However, as you can see you don't have an action which maps to that particular route because your only route expects an `id` parameter (but your action contains a `request` parameter).

Switching to using the model directly in the view should be enough to fix this issue and should work posting directly to `api/values/json`.

---

> I thought that `{ id = RouteParameter.Optional }` was optional as in it would accept the ID

That generally would be the case, however, in your route you have a constraint set on the `id` which says it has to contain *some* value - this renders your default value obsolete.

Comment: I thought that `{id = RouteParameter.Optional}` was optional as in it would accept without ID. Thanks for your answer, cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your further explanation, appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your controller can accept your POCO type directly, no need to serialize from the string by hand:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(HttpRequestMessage request, [FromBody]JsonModel)
```

I'm not sure that's the problem, though. When using WebAPI, I'd stay away from the ActionName attribute. I think it's a lot cleaner to have a separate controller for each type with simple Get/Post, etc. methods. So, in your case:

Controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(HttpRequestMessage request, [FromBody]JsonModel)
{}
```

Then you simply post to:

```
api/values
```

...and, finally, your route config:

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"
```